# Templates in a google-apps-script Web App

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

The [best practice guidelines for Google Apps Script web-apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices) say that loading data asynchronously is better than loading in templates - which I get.

But using jQuery to append lots of HTML seems messy (to me at least). e.g. to append a table row...

```
$('<tr>' + _
     '<td>' + data[0] + '</td>' +
     '<td>' + data[1] + '</td>' +
     ...
'</tr>').appendTo(table);
```

Are there any templating libraries or front-end frameworks that work well with GAS? Are there any tutorials or examples out there?

Comment: I've seen a few [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) implementations floating around. Use github's search feature or just google it to see what crops up.

Comment: Also keep in mind that GAS has its own templating system via [Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates). You can use that to implement server-side driven templating.

Comment: Thanks @DimuDesigns - Vue.js looks interesting - a kind of lightweight (maybe) angular.js. I'll check it out.